Embedded terminal for Nautilus >= version 43
When I used Ubuntu 22.04, there was a great Nautilus extension called nautilus-terminal which could embed a terminal in Nautilus windows (as shown below)

However, the nautilus-terminal is not supported since nautilus's version 43 because of the changed APIs of the nautilus plugin. I found this out after I updated my Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04, and my nautilus version is 46.2.
An embedded terminal in Nautilus benefits me a lot, but I can not find any replacement for Nautilus. I had seen a nautilus extension called nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal, but I could not find its instructions. After installing it, I could not find any setting for the terminal in Nautilus.

I do not use nautilus but it seems this explains it, read from 3- https://www.baeldung.com/linux/gnome-nautilus-context-open-terminal

Unfortunately, as you can read for yourself, the developer of the nautilus-terminal extension gave up after yet another breaking major change in the API of nautilus.
The nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal you mention merely provides a right-menu entry in nautilus allowing to open a terminal window in the current directory. That will be your only next best option to relatively quickly open a terminal in the current directory, but already entails quite some overhead comparing to have a prompt readily available.
The keyboard tends to be quickest:

There is relatively fast, though crippled, keyboard access that seems to be broken in Ubuntu 22.04, but that may work in 24.04: hit Ctrl+F10 to open the "Current folder" menu, then hit e twice to jump to the "Open in terminal" then press Enter. I said "crippled" because it would only take two keystrokes if the menu hotkey e were not simultaneously assigned to "Refresh" and "Open in terminal".

Alternatively, you can use the context menu (Shift+F10), but that works only when either nothing is selected (when first entering a directory) or when a directory is selected.



Thank. I learned to use shortcut keys. They are much faster than the mouse operation.
